# How do we calculate distance and centroid for vectors that contain negative values ?

Tags: clustering, data-mining, normalization, similarities, distance-functions

I would like to know if its possible to measure distance among vectors that contain positive and negative values such in this example :

```
       c1     c2      c3      c4      c5     c6
V1  [-1.62  -0.60   -0.44   -0.97   -0.70  -0.26]    
V2  [-0.46  -0.84   -0.30   1.00    0.35    0.6 ]
V3.. etc
```

where :- 
Vi which has negative values its not related to Cj and so on ... this dataset same as when produced by applying SVD.

My questions are:

1- if i would like to compute similarity/ distance among vectors which distance /similarity measure can be used?

2- in order to apply clustering algorithm (k-means) to find k clusters from such data .. how do we calculate centroid ..

are there any processing step must be done ? i would be thank any one can give me a notes about this case ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Euclidean distance only looks at the differences of two points, not at the absolute values.

Why do you think

```
(x1-x2)**2
```

might not work with negative numbers?

Be careful if you use cosine distance though: a vector that is all zero *does* cause problems with cosine.